# FFMPEG script to convert all Webm files in a folder to Gif, and then delete those Webm

Tags: scripting, ffmpeg, gif, file-conversion, webm

I'm using FFmpeg with DirectoryMonitor, a folder watching program. When a webm is added to the folder i want to execute a script to convert all webm files in that folder to gif, and then delete those webm files.

Comment: What is your question ?

Comment: What's the correct command to convert all webm files in a folder to gif, and then delete those webm files?

Comment: This doesn't sound like a programming question - you might be better off asking on http://superuser.com.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ffmpeg can often deduce the output type by its file extension, so just write to a .gif and you're usually good.

```bash
#!/bin/bash

for w in ./*.webm; do 
  ffmpeg -i $w ${w%.*}.gif && rm $w 
done
```

Comment: OP can do it in two passes: first pass generates optimum palette i.e. `ffmpeg -i $w -vf palettegen ${w%.*}.png` and 2nd pass generates GIF i.e. `ffmpeg -i $w -i ${w%.*}.png -vf paletteuse ${w%.*}.gif`

Comment: I noticed that I had to specify the .png file as a virtual device (`-lavfi`) in order to get this to work. So the second command would be `ffmpeg -i $w -i ${w%.*}.png -lavfi paletteuse ${w%.*}.gif`.

Comment: `-lavfi` isn't a virtual device. It's an alias for `-filter_complex`.